# How to load external JS file in component using ember-cli

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have created an ember app with a `component`, and I am trying to figure out how I can load a external JS file that is stored in the `vendor` dir of the app within the component.  The code for the component looks like the following,

```
// app/components/bubbles-page.js

import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({

    didInsertElement: function() {
    // this.$() is a scoped selector to the current view

    // bubbles();



    // window.onload = bubbles();

    // the below line gives the following error,
    this.$().bubbles();
    // ERROR
    //TypeError: this.$(...).bubbles is not a function
    // END ERROR
  }

});
```

And the `ember-cli-build.js` looks like the following,

```
/* global require, module */
var EmberApp = require('ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app');

module.exports = function(defaults) {
  var app = new EmberApp(defaults, {
    // Add options here

    // 
  });

  // Use `app.import` to add additional libraries to the generated
  // output files.
  //
  // If you need to use different assets in different
  // environments, specify an object as the first parameter. That
  // object's keys should be the environment name and the values
  // should be the asset to use in that environment.
  //
  // If the library that you are including contains AMD or ES6
  // modules that you would like to import into your application
  // please specify an object with the list of modules as keys
  // along with the exports of each module as its value.
  app.import( app.bowerDirectory + '/d3/d3.min.js');
  app.import('vendor/bubbles.js');

  return app.toTree();
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `ember-cli-build.js` seems ok.

As for your component file, you can use `Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', callback)` to wait for the DOM to render and then call your jQuery plugin.

Also, normally with jQuery plugins, you would have to pass a jQuery selector with which to call the function.

Try the following:

```
// app/components/bubbles-page.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({

    didRender() {
        this.$('.my-bubbles-container').bubbles();
    }

});
```

Replace `.my-bubbles-container` with your jQuery selector. I am not familiar with the jQuery plugin you're trying to use but normally that's how jQuery plugins would be used.

You can read more about how to initialize a jQuery component on [this blog post][1].

### Updated answer

After learning that your `bubbles.js` file wasn't a jQuery plugin and that it was a function that operates on the global window, you can call it like this:

```
// app/components/bubbles-page.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({

    didRender() {
        bubbles();
    }

});
```

If your function is a global function, you will need to add `/* global bubbles */` to your component file, or add `bubbles` to the `predef` array in the `.jshintrc` file to avoid the JSHint errors.

Comment: `this.$()` should be a valid selector for the current component. Just curious - why schedule that into `afterRender`? Doesn't `didInsertElement` get called after the component is rendered already?

Comment: @PatchRickWalsh, it looks like as per the docs that you could use either in this case and that "didRender runs after didInsertElement (it also runs on subsequent re-renders)." so I guess it depends on the use case. http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/06/12/ember-1-13-0-released.html

Comment: The link to [this blog post][1[ didn't make it into this post properly. You may want to amend that @tina. I'd like to see what that was.

Comment: Here is a twiddle with a working jQuery plugin in a component as an example:  https://ember-twiddle.com/4c464007f11b1eec3313bbc29cf2f30e  : )

Answer (score 2):

This might be a silly question but did you restart your `ember serve` after adding the import to `ember-cli-build`? Changes to the `Brocfile` or `ember-cli-build` won’t be picked up until you restart.

Another thing you could try is to add `{ type: 'vendor'}` to your import statement: `app.import('vendor/bubbles.js', {type: 'vendor'});`

Comment: yes I have restarted the ember server several times.

Comment: Is there maybe an error with vender/bubbles where it's not attaching itself to $ correctly? Is that a module you've written yourself?

Comment: Sometimes I grab a CDN of something and later realize that it's a fork of the jQuery plugin that is now vanilla JS. Watch out for that.